# Conversion from string "INSERT INTO Products_Archive VAL" to type 'Double' is not valid

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

this is my sql command:

```vb
 sqlcom1 = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Products_Archive VALUES ('" + arno1 + "','" +
    ds.Tables("Products").Rows(myval).Item(0) + "','" + 
    ds.Tables("Products").Rows(myval).Item(1) + "','" + 
    ds.Tables("Products").Rows(myval).Item(2) + "','" + 
    ds.Tables("Products").Rows(myval).Item(3) + "','" + 
    ds.Tables("Products").Rows(myval).Item(4) + "','" + 
    ds.Tables("Products").Rows(myval).Item(5) + "'," + 
    ds.Tables("Products_Archive").Rows(myval).Item(6) + "," + 
    ds.Tables("Products_Archive").Rows(myval).Item(7) + ",'" + 
    ds.Tables("Products").Rows(myval).Item(8) + ",'" + 
    ds.Tables("Products").Rows(myval).Item(9) + "'," + 
    ds.Tables("Products").Rows(myval).Item(10) + "," + 
    ds.Tables("Products").Rows(myval).Item(11) + "," + 
    ds.Tables("Products").Rows(myval).Item(12) + "," + 
    ds.Tables("Products").Rows(myval).Item(13) + "," + 
    ds.Tables("Products").Rows(myval).Item(14) + ")", con1)

 sqlcom1.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

The columns for datasets 6,7,8,10,11,12,13,and 14 have datatype `bigint`.
However, I always get this error

```
Conversion from string "INSERT INTO Products_Archive VAL" to type 'Double' is not valid.
```

By the way, I use sql server and vb.net

Comment: You know if you used `String.Format` and a few newlines, your code would be a thousand times easier to read.

Comment: Also, I think you've forgotten to *ask a question*.

Comment: how am i suppose to prevent the error?

Comment: can you post the table structure?

Comment: Try using `&` instead of `+`.

Comment: I have already tried it.nothing happened

Comment: i have checked the table structures and they are correct. the datatypes are also the same.

Comment: try print sqlcom1.CommandText and post the result

Comment: print the sqlCom1.CommandText and comment this code :  sqlcom1.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: i already did Sir. Do you think the error is about the conversion of string? actually, the dataset item is already in bigint type. how am i supposed to input it correctly in the insert statement to match the bigint column?

Comment: what is the CommandText content?

Comment: the insert statement sir

Comment: Have you tried replacing *all* `+`s with `&`s? Judging by the error message, it's trying to convert your *SQL statement* rather than any of the values you are putting into it. For some reason, it is treating the SQL query string as a number, which may be the consequence of using `+` instead of `&`.

Comment: Sir Andriy M, Sir lc and Sir Iswanto San!! thank you so much for your help. the error is solved. I forgot to replace all of the +S with &s. I overlooked it. Thank you for reminding Sir Andriy!May God bless you all..:)

Comment: @lc.: Please consider posting your comment about replacing the `+`s with `&`s as an answer so that the OP can accept it formally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VB, you should use `&` instead of `+` to concatenate strings.

With `+`, in your case it is (wrongly) interpreting your statement as a sum and not a concatenation. The error is coming from the implicit conversion of your SQL statement string to a `double` in order to perform the addition.